# WPF application using a MVVM pattern is not displaying data as expected

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am loading data succesfully into the viewModel, but the data is not displaying as i would expect in the view (It does on the first load if the search term is hard coded in to the service layer.

Basically - The observable list of characters is being filled in the viewmodel but not being displayed in the view.

Pulling my hair out - and I dont have much left - any help truly appreciated!!

Data Service - data is consistently returned as expected...

```
public async Task<List<Character>> GetCharactersAsync(string searchTerm)
        {
            //searchTerm = "T";
            var timestamp = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
            var hash = GetMarvelHash(timestamp);
            //assemble the URL
            string url = String.Format("http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?nameStartsWith={0}&ts=" + timestamp + "&apikey=" + PublicMarvelAPIKey + "&hash=" + hash, searchTerm);
            
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result; 
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(data);
                //deserialize the data
                var characterWrapper = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CharacterDataWrapper>(data);
                
                var characters = new List<Character>();

                foreach (var character in characterWrapper.Data.Results)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(character.Thumbnail.path) && character.Thumbnail.path != "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/b/40/image_not_available" && character.Thumbnail.path != "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/f/60/4c002e0305708")
                    {
                        if (character.Name.Length > 16)
                        {
                            character.Name = character.Name.Substring(0, 13) + "...";
                        }
                        character.Thumbnail.small = character.Thumbnail.path + "/portrait_uncanny." + character.Thumbnail.extension;
                        character.Thumbnail.large = character.Thumbnail.path + "/standard_fantastic." + character.Thumbnail.extension;
                        // Add the character to the list
                        characters.Add(character);
                    }
                }
                //console dump the list of characters
                
                return characters;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

The viewmodel

```
    public class MasterViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly IMarvelService _marvelService;

        public MasterViewModel(IMarvelService marvelService)
        {
            _marvelService = marvelService;
            Characters = new ObservableCollection<Character>();
            LoadCharactersAsync();
            StartTimer();
        }


        private ObservableCollection<Character> _characters;
        public ObservableCollection<Character> Characters
        {
            get { return _characters; }
            set
            {
                _characters = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Characters));
            }
        }

        private string _searchTerm;
        public string SearchTerm
        {
            get { return _searchTerm; }
            set
            {
                _searchTerm = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchTerm));

            }
        }

        private async Task LoadCharactersAsync()
        {
            var characters = await _marvelService.GetCharactersAsync(SearchTerm);

            if (characters != null)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    Characters.Clear();
                    foreach (var character in characters)
                    {
                        Characters.Add(character);
                        Debug.WriteLine(character.Name);
                    }
                });

            }
        }


        public RelayCommand SearchCommand => new RelayCommand(SearchAsync, (o) => true);

        public void SearchAsync(object parameter)
        {
            LoadCharactersAsync();
        }

        private string _currentTime;

        public string CurrentTime
        {
            get { return _currentTime; }
            set
            {
                if (_currentTime != value)
                {
                    _currentTime = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentTime));
                }
            }
        }
```

The View

```
<Page x:Class="SoftwareUI.Views.MasterPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SoftwareUI.Views" xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:SoftwareUI.ViewModels" xmlns:models="clr-namespace:SoftwareUI.Models" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=models:Character}"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="MasterPage">

    <Grid>
        <Label>MasterPage</Label>

        <ListView x:Name="Cards" ItemsSource="{Binding Characters}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
       
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The code behind

```
  public MasterPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //DataContext = new MasterViewModel(marvelService: new MarvelService());
            DataContext = new MasterViewModel(new MarvelService());
        }
```

The Character Class

```
    public class Character : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int id;
        public int Id {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged("Id");  } 
        }
        
        private string name;
        public string Name {
            get {return name; }
            set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } 
        }

        private string description;
        public string Description {
            get {return description; }
            set {description = value; OnPropertyChanged("Description"); } 
        }

        private Thumbnail thumbnail;
        public Thumbnail Thumbnail {
            get { return thumbnail; }
            set { thumbnail = value; OnPropertyChanged("Thumbnail"); } 
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class Thumbnail
    {
        public string path { get; set; }
        public string extension { get; set; }
        public string small { get; set; }
        public string large { get; set; }
    }
```

There doesnt seem to be a problem accessing the data, only in the binding to the controls in the view.  When the page is first loaded and the searchterm is hard coded - the characters are displayed correctly.  Also its worth noting (maybe) that this is a masterPage, nested in a mainWindow...

Comment: There is information missing here.  OK, if the search term is hard coded it loads the characters fine.  But suppose the search term is not  hard-coded.  I see you kicking off the search anyway with what I assume must be an empty search term.  Does  *that* search still return characters?  Have you put breakpoints or logging statements in that code to verify it?

Comment: Thanks Joe - It appears (I think) to be related to the fact that I have a Page nested in a layout.  There is a MainWindow (that serves as a layout.  With a nested master page (side note:- later I'm adding a details page that will also be nested in the MainWindow).  If I put the search box directly in the Nested Master Page - everthing works as it should - the Listview displays the updated Characters from the ViewModel.  The search box (Im afraid) need to go in the MainWindow (like a sidebar).  Any ideas how to wire this up?  Both pages are currently have same dataContext (MasterViewmodel). Thx

Comment: That's just a matter of ensuring that an object's `DataContext` is what you think it is.  When it is not, bindings will fail and you should see warning/error output in the output window indicating this fact.  Also in the XAML Binding Failures window